# Indexing Cell arrays for more efficient performance

Tags: matlab

I have the following code to display a 9-by-3 cell array:

```
data = cell (9,3);

col1 = [2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 15, 16];

col2 = {[1 1], [1 5], [3 9], [4 2], [4 6], [6 2], [7 6], [6 9], [9 9]};

col3 = {[2 3 4 5 8],[1 3 5 8],[1 2 5 7 8],[1 2 3 6 7],[3 4 7 8],[2 4 8 9],[2 4 5 9],[4 5 7 9],[2 6 7 8]};

k = length(data);
for i = 1:k 
    data{i,1} = col1(i); 
    data{i,2} = col2{i};
    data{i,3} = col3{i};
end
data
```

Please, can this code be more efficiently written using a form of indexing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have written code to assign a 9 x 3 cell array, which can also be written as:

```
data2 = [num2cell(col1') col2' col3']

data2 = 

    [ 2]    [1x2 double]    [1x5 double]
    [ 3]    [1x2 double]    [1x4 double]
    [ 5]    [1x2 double]    [1x5 double]
    [ 7]    [1x2 double]    [1x5 double]
    [ 8]    [1x2 double]    [1x4 double]
    [11]    [1x2 double]    [1x4 double]
    [12]    [1x2 double]    [1x4 double]
    [15]    [1x2 double]    [1x4 double]
    [16]    [1x2 double]    [1x4 double]
```